# Combining given column and row value

Tags: excel

I have used min to find the minimum value of an array, then used MATCH with match type as 0; this gives me the row which the value was found at.

I understand all of that, however I want to retrieve the value at, for example, A(F2), assuming the value returned at F2 is the result of the MATCH method.

How can I do this?

Comment: Use `INDIRECT()`

Comment: @Gary'sStudent Checking it out now, thanks.

Comment: `=index(a:a, f2)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been solved, adding this answer so I can mark it as so.

I just used `INDIRECT()` to get the value from a string, and used the concatenation shorthand `&`, e.g: `=INDIRECT("A" & F2)`.

**EDIT:** As Slai stated, I could have also used `=INDEX(A:A, F2)`

Comment: use `=INDEX(A:A, F1)` instead https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb687891.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396#Volatile%20and%20Non-Volatile%20Functions